# How certain types like Image can be Dispose using the Dispose() method

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

Let's say I have a large `Image` object, if I call the `Dispose()` method of this object I can easily see the memory consumption of my application be reduced, since I just cleared the object from memory.

But what if I have my own type/class and want to dispose an instance of it, which, let's say, contains a `byte[]` array (which I think is the same thing the `Image` class has internally). How would I go about implementing `IDisposable` so when `Dispose()` is called the `byte[]` is instantly disposed from memory. Without me having to wait for `GC`?

What if it were a `string` instead of a `byte[]`?

Comment: Can you not just declare your Class like `class SomeClass : IDisposable` also if you want to know if something will work in regards to calling the `Dispose method` you could something like this `((IDisposable)someObject).Dispose()`; normally if it Implements IDisposable it will Dispose properly usually you can determine that even at design / compile time because if it doesn't you would get an error

Comment: Yes, I can. but what should I put inside `Dispose()` in order for my variable's contents to be instantly disposed, like the `Image` class does?

Comment: for Items that do not Implement `IDisposable` and if you are not calling `GC` then set the Object's `value = to null` you can also wrap the code around a `using(){}` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory consumption reduces in two cases:

1. Garbage collector has freed up the memory, and
2. Unmanaged code was executed which has freed up the memory instantaneously.

Image data example is the second case. Images are held by OS and when you dispose an image, operating system is called to free the image buffer. This is operating system's job because operating system is the one to render images on the screen, which then depends on hardware and drivers. In addition to this, graphical operating system is extremely optimized to work with image data - no wonder then that it is used to work with images when needed.

It is completely opposite when you create your own disposable class. Executing dispose actually does nothing, regarding the memory footprint. Even garbage collecting won't reduce the memory usage as long as there is a live pointer pointing to the disposed class.

Class should implement IDisposable only if it allocates some unmanaged resources - file handles, images, sockets (which are only a kind of file handles from OS point of view), etc. Dispose method is supposed to free up only the unmanaged resources. There is no point in setting the fields to null and do similar silly things.

Answer (score 2):

Objects in .NET only exist as long as some sort of reference exists to them.  Objects that don't exist don't hold references to anything.  If during a garbage-collection cycle an object is found to have no references to it anywhere except as `WeakReference` targets, the system will invalidate those `WeakReference` objects, whereupon the objects will no longer have any references pointing to them and will thus cease to exist.  If the only non-weak references to an object are in the system's list of objects that have registered `Finalize` methods, the object will be removed from that list and added to the system's list of objects whose `Finalize` method should be run at first opportunity.  Once the system run's an object's `Finalize` method, it will be removed from the latter list and unless a reference has been stored somewhere else, it will cease to exist.

The reason `Image` has a dispose method is that its construction often asks for the creation of things that are not .NET objects and/or asks outside entities to do things on its behalf (e.g. grant exclusive read access to a file).  If a `Bitmap` were abandoned without `Dispose` being called upon it, and if it didn't have a `Finalize` method, the `Bitmap` object would cease to exist, but any outside objects whose creation it requested would continue to exist, and any outside entities that were acting on its behalf would continue to do so.

Because the creation of a byte array does not require the construction of anything that isn't a .NET object, nor does it require any outside entitites to do anything on its behalf, there is no need for an array which is no longer required to do anything other than cease to exist.  Likewise for an object which holds such an array.